# Parsing strings by using RegEx

Tags: c#, regex

First let me post you some example strings:

```
string_position = ("\"%s\";\"%s\";\"%s\";\"\";\"%s\"\r\n\"%s\";\"%s\";\"%s\";\"%s - %s\";\"%s\";\"%.0f\";\"FR\";\"%.2f\";\"%.2f\";\"%.2f\";\"%s\";\"%s\";\"%s\";\"%s\";\"\";\"\";\"\";\"\";\"\";\"\";\"\";\"\";\"\";\"\";\"\";\"\";\"\";\"\";\"B\"\r\n",POSNR_NR_ID,POSNR_NR_ID,POSNR,POSNR_NR_ID,ARTNR_NR_ID,POSNR_NR_ID,CP90NAME,TEXT1,TEXT2,ARTNR_NR_ID,CNT,WIDTH,HEIGHT,DEPTH,INFO1,INFO2,INFO3,INFO4)

string_position = ("STK_PD_BEZ|%s|STK_ID|%s|STK_EBENE|0|ID|%s\r\nSTK_ID|%s|ORDERPOS|%s|STK_EBENE|1|STK_PD_BEZ|%s|STK_FLAENGE|%.2f|STK_FBREITE|%.2f|STK_FDICKE|%.2f|ID|%s|PARENTID|%s\r\n",POSNR,ORDERID,POSNR_NR_ID,ORDERID,POSSTR,CP90NAME,WIDTH,DEPTH,HEIGHT,ARTNR_NR_ID,POSNR_NR_ID)
```

So I want to parse those strings, but I don't know how I could start. As I result I want to have two arrays for each string, for example (string 2):

```
array_a[0] = STK_PD_BEZ|%s;
array_b[0] = POSNR;

array_a[1] = STK_ID|%s;
array_b[1] = ORDERID;
```

etc...

I hope you understand my problem. I have to find the complementary "variable" to each %s. So the algorithm has to work with any string that looks like the ones I've posted.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: You could improve a little by not naming your samples the same and by explaining the differences and similarities between the 2 strings. I'm lost what to do with example 1

Comment: so you need everything btween %s of just the stuff right before

Comment: @rerun and Henk: Take a look at the second STRING_POSITION. That's what I tried to explain with my 2 arrays. The "STK_PD_BEZ|%s" belongs to (if you srcroll right) to "POSNR". And that's what the parser has to find out. (Which %s belongs to the complementary variable)

Comment: You can try to experiment with RegExr: http://gskinner.com/RegExr to study and test new expressions

Comment: Still don't understand what the 1st string is for. Just to confuse us?

Comment: @ Henk: No, not to confuse you... My strings can look like that one... For example, as a result I should get arrays like: array_a[0] = %s; array_b[0] = POSNR_NR_ID; and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just quick implementation, hope it will be useful. I don't go with regex for this particualr task. I think simple parser will be enough here.

```
        // const string test = "STK_PD_BEZ|%s|STK_ID|%s|STK_EBENE|0|ID|%s\r\nSTK_ID|%s|ORDERPOS|%s|STK_EBENE|1|STK_PD_BEZ|%s|STK_FLAENGE|%.2f|STK_FBREITE|%.2f|STK_FDICKE|%.2f|ID|%s|PARENTID|%s\r\n,POSNR,ORDERID,POSNR_NR_ID,ORDERID,POSSTR,CP90NAME,WIDTH,DEPTH,HEIGHT,ARTNR_NR_ID,POSNR_NR_ID";

        const string test = "\"%s\";\"%s\";\"%s\";\"\";\"%s\"\r\n\"%s\";\"%s\";\"%s\";\"%s - %s\";\"%s\";\"%.0f\";\"FR\";\"%.2f\";\"%.2f\";\"%.2f\";\"%s\";\"%s\";\"%s\";\"%s\";\"\";\"\";\"\";\"\";\"\";\"\";\"\";\"\";\"\";\"\";\"\";\"\";\"\";\"\";\"B\"\r\n,POSNR_NR_ID,POSNR_NR_ID,POSNR,POSNR_NR_ID,ARTNR_NR_ID,POSNR_NR_ID,CP90NAME,TEXT1,TEXT2,ARTNR_NR_ID,CNT,WIDTH,HEIGHT,DEPTH,INFO1,INFO2,INFO3,INFO4";

        // [0] - format string
        // [1..n] - arguments for format
        string[] args = test.Split(',');

        // Source parts divided by delimiters. You can extend it.
        string[] parts = args[0].Split("|\r\n;-".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        
        // Format - arg pair
        var parsed = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();

        // Current format string
        var format = new List<string>();
        
        // Start from 1 since we skip format string
        int currentValue = 1;

        // Building
        foreach (var part in parts)
        {
            if (part.Contains("%"))
            {
                format.Add(part);
                parsed.Add(Tuple.Create(string.Join("|", format), args[currentValue++]));

                format.Clear();
            }
            else format.Add(part);
        }

        // Printing
        foreach (var pair in parsed)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", pair.Item1, pair.Item2);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Output:

> STK_PD_BEZ|%s = POSNR
>
> STK_ID|%s = ORDERID
>
> STK_EBENE|0|ID|%s = POSNR_NR_ID
>
> STK_ID|%s = ORDERID
>
> ORDERPOS|%s = POSSTR
>
> STK_EBENE|1|STK_PD_BEZ|%s = CP90NAME
>
> STK_FLAENGE|%.2f = WIDTH
>
> STK_FBREITE|%.2f = DEPTH
>
> STK_FDICKE|%.2f = HEIGHT
>
> ID|%s = ARTNR_NR_ID
>
> PARENTID|%s = POSNR_NR_ID

Output2:

> "%s" = POSNR_NR_ID
>
> "%s" = POSNR_NR_ID
>
> "%s" = POSNR
>
> ""|"%s" = POSNR_NR_ID
>
> "%s" = ARTNR_NR_ID
>
> "%s" = POSNR_NR_ID
>
> "%s" = CP90NAME
>
> "%s  = TEXT1
>
> %s" = TEXT2
>
> "%s" = ARTNR_NR_ID
>
> "%.0f" = CNT
>
> "FR"|"%.2f" = WIDTH
>
> "%.2f" = HEIGHT
>
> "%.2f" = DEPTH
>
> "%s" = INFO1
>
> "%s" = INFO2
>
> "%s" = INFO3
>
> "%s" = INFO4

---

**UPDATE**:

> Without formal specification parser's code will be rather empirical than formally valid. So first of all I would recommend start with making specification for your input then you can easily make parser which would accept all valid strings. For example you can start with [Syntax diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_diagram)

Comment: This works for my second string, but as a result for my first string the output is empty...

Comment: You are not provide any specification for input strings, output results. What can be treated as delimiters? Do you need to preserve formatting (i.e. spacers, quotes etc)? How to detect format description is ended? All I have just two samples. So I just write very straightful example how you can start. I'll update my code.